# How to provide basic auth credentials from kubernetes secrets for deploying prometheus with helm?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-secrets

I want to deploy Prometheus on Kubernetes cluster using Helm, and I have multiple endpoints to scrape with basic auth. I have made 3 different secrets for each of the endpoints, but I don't know how to read those creds from secrets and add them to the values.yaml so it cal load them.

This is part of my values.yaml, adding the scraping target:

```yaml
      - job_name: test
        basic_auth: 
          username: ?
          password: ?
        static_configs:
        - targets:
          - test.com
```

I want to add such env to the config so I can load the creds:

```yaml
        env:
          - name: PASS
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: "my-secret"
                key: "password"
```

But, I can not understand how to do this, considering the configmap template of the chart:
https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/prometheus/templates/cm.yaml